# If a set has a second category subset then second category

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Let $(X,d)$ is a **complete** metric space.
I’m trying to prove below :

“If a set has a second category subset then it is second category as well.”

I know that a set is first category iff we can write it as countable union of nowhere dense sets. Also, a set is second category iff it is not first category.

It sounds very very clear for me but I could not give an exact proof with contradiction. I’m not sure how should I use completeness. Is completeness really necessary there?

It can be a nonsense. I’m sorry for this in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $Y \subset X$ is of second category in $X$. If possible let $X=\cup_n C_n$ where each $C_n$ is nowhere dense. Then $Y=\cup_n D_n$ where $D_n=Y\cap C_n$. All you have to do is to verify that $D_n$ is nowhere dense. This  is obvious because any subset of a nowhere dense set is nowhere dense.

Note: let $X$ be any metric space of first category and $Y$ consist of a single point. Then $Y$ is of second category in itself because it is a complete metric space. So the result is false if the assumption is that $Y$ is of second category in itself. We have to assume that $Y$ is of second category as a subset of $X$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Completeness is not necessary right?

Comment: Right, completeness is not necessary.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer :)